# How to Change Default Inputs for JComboBox and JButton

Tags: java, user-interface, input

How do I make the Enter key trigger a JComboBox or JButton in a GUI rather than having to hit the Space key? I have an assortment of text fields and check boxes with buttons and combo boxes in between. I'd like to avoid having to switch between hitting space and enter and rather only have to hit enter for all components.

```
package koning.personal.dungeonsanddragons;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

JFrame window = new JFrame("testGUI");
JPanel windowPanel = new JPanel();

public static JLabel labelSize;
public static JComboBox<String> comboSize;

public static JLabel labelButton;
public static JButton buttonButton;

public test () {
    super();

    labelSize = new JLabel("Monster Size:");
    String[] sizeChoices = { "None", "Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Huge", "Colossal"};
    comboSize = new JComboBox<String>(sizeChoices);
    comboSize.setToolTipText("The creature's size.");

    labelButton = new JLabel("Button:");
    buttonButton = new JButton();

    windowPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    windowPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    windowPanel.add(labelSize);
    windowPanel.add(comboSize);
    windowPanel.add(labelButton);
    windowPanel.add(buttonButton);
    windowPanel.setVisible(true);

    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.add(windowPanel);

    comboSize.addActionListener(handler);
    buttonButton.addActionListener(handler);
}

ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();
public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventFocus){
        if (eventFocus.getSource() == comboSize){
            buttonButton.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        if (eventFocus.getSource() == buttonButton){
            comboSize.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test GUITest = new test();
}

}
```

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes. I refactored SF23's answer and applied it to my JButtons. I did the same to my ComboBoxes after learning about showPopup()

Comment: Using https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, I made some sample code for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a KeyListener and execute doClick

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                btn.doClick();

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: please provide a code example that shows how this could be done. One line answers are often not as good as a thorough answer.

Comment: Going in the right direction but you could add a bit more things, some code examples or a link to a tutorial covering the subject.

Comment: What would I use in place of doClick() for a JComboBox? This solution works for buttons but I do not know how to tell the ComboBox to expand upon hitting Enter as it does with Space.

Comment: I found it. I used showPopup() in place of doClick().

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have something happen when the enter button is pressed (pressed once and something happens with all the components) then you can add a KeyListener to the JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Examplpe");
//here you create and add the components to the frame
```

and then you can add a KeyListener:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){//this is the if block I'm refering to in the following explanation
            //do something with all the components
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

and then when you press `Enter`, the code inside the if block will be executed.

Hope this helps :)